# Greeks Letter in RStudio + Sweave

Tags: pdftex, knitr, sweave, rstudio

This is my Rsweave reproducible code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=1cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc} 
\usepackage{csquotes}  
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references}

\begin{document}

<<maincode,include=FALSE, echo=TRUE>>=
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
@

<<results='asis',echo=FALSE>>=

summary_matrix<-matrix(nrow=3,ncol=4)
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")

colnames(summary_matrix)=c('sample A','sample B','sample C','sample D')

summary_matrix<-as.data.frame(summary_matrix)

rownames(summary_matrix)[1] <-  "$E(x_{s_{t+1}}^{can})$";
rownames(summary_matrix)[2] <-  "$E(x_{s_{t+1}}^{can})$";
rownames(summary_matrix)[3] <-  "$H(x_{s_{t+1}}^{can})$";


kable(summary_matrix, booktabs = TRUE, caption = "My table", escape = FALSE)

@


\end{document}
```

I would like to replace the x with Delta and the H with Sigma. In Latex would be $\Delta$ and $\sigma$, but I cant do it here.

How can I solve this?

Any help?